# Saving values in same column every time form is submitted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have one form which user can submit and update previously stored data in database column. Is just simple input field which can take string.

I want to make it that if user come back after a day or an hour and submit new value on the form to save it in column separated with comma from previous one.

This is the form

```
{{ Form::open() }}
           {{ Form::text('value', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'value', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) }}
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And I've tried to use `implode()` in my controller to do this but instead of add second submit it's delete previous one and insert the new one.

```
$value=implode(",",(array)Input::get('value'));
$user->user_value = $value;
$user->save();
```

It's seems pretty simple yet I can't figured it out. Can anyone help me?

Note: User can submit one value at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the value every time you submit the form. You should concatenate the old value to the new one before saving. Like so:

```
if (empty($user->user_value))
    $user->user_value = \Input::get('value');
else
    $user->user_value = $user->user_value . ',' . \Input::get('value');
$user->save();
```

Comment: This seems to work. Just a question: How can I not save the comma if this is first submission of the form?

Comment: you can do something like` $user->user_value = $user->user_value ? $user->user_value.','.\Input::get('value');`. But are you doing an update or new record creation?

Comment: I have updated my answer with what to do when the first value is empty. Can you let me know where you get this error?

Comment: It is working like this. The error was on this `$user->user_value = $user->user_value ? $user->user_value.','.\Input::get('value');`

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to retrieve the current value from the database, merge the new value(from the form) with the current as strings and then save the merged value.